I can't transfer Ethereum from my Ethereum MIST Browser wallet. Please tell me how to transfer the wallet to a keystore file
The Ethereum in my MIST wallet that I was saving on my computer is not being sent due to a problem with the MIST browser. I forgot the recovery code and only have the keystore file and password. Is there a way to transfer it to another wallet?
Wallet address is 0x62e43076256A12C6d1ccFb19f1c9db4B8a35AAf0
Please help...

Mist was deprecated a long time ago. I think MyEtherWallet and MyCrypto used to support those old type of wallets, or at least they had an old version that supported them.
